# Possible to use reCAPTCHA on a site without HTTPS?

Tags: recaptcha

I have a simple informational site that has no ecommerce aspects. It has a comment submission form that I'd like to protect with reCAPTCHA.

Is there any way to use reCAPTCHA without converting the site to HTTPS (at increased cost for certificate and hosting) ?

Comment: HTTPS costs exactly nothing. see https://letsencrypt.org. If your hoster doesn't offer HTTPS, get a different hoster. It's 2018.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It could costs thousands of dollars if you have a complex website that was not developed with https in mind....

Comment: Then you'd probably not be asking this, here, about a comments section. Even so, no, that's not true, letsencrypt does support wildcard domains now, and you could simply have enough rewrite rules on your webserver to simply forward every non-tls request. Again, this is 2018. There shouldn't be any excuses.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That is not viable. letsencrypt is a nightmare when you have many sites to deal with.  There is simply no need to secure text only sites.  It also does not answer the question...WITHOUT HTTPS

Comment: for which text only site would you need a captcha that you don't want HTTPS for? Letsencrypt a nightmare?

Comment: There certs only last 90 days.  So yeah, that's a nightmare.  Especially when you have a LOT of sites.  As for what sites, literally what the OP stated.

Comment: @JustinEmlay certs are autorenewed...

Comment: @iguypouf - nope, not always.  Not all applications support auto renew and even those that do, it can fail.

Answer (score 4):

yes you can they have a javascript api for that also you can verify the response from serverside!

> https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display