# How to verify domain for Google recaptcha v3

Tags: laravel-5, recaptcha-v3

I'm trying to use Google ReCaptcha V3 for my site, but when I load the page always get a message "Invalid site key or not loaded in api.js".

So for the first question, I need to make sure Google Recaptcha V3 can run on the local environment, right? (without SSL)

If it can run, How to verify domain or site key is correct?

HTML&JS

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{{env('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY')}}"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:
[Google Recaptcha V3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mRR9.png)

Please help me :)

Comment: I already read it and try to develop like an example of document only frontend section, but still, get an error as I mentioned before.

Comment: The documentation is 100% clear and you have to be more careful. Otherwise, upload samples of your code or your screenshots in order to understand where exactly is the problem.

Comment: Insert your code and your screenshots inside your question.

Comment: I already added it. Please check ;)

Comment: For your first question I have this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320279/possible-to-use-recaptcha-on-a-site-without-https

Comment: That's V2, right? And I already found that before.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to include the sitekey in the script tag itself:

You have: `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js`

You want: `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<v3_site_key>`